# how to get a ratio of each class in sklearn k-nn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, knn

Blue will be predicted as a result of this case when k is 5 because there are 3 out of 5 blue dots.
And, I know how to score the accuracy. But What I want to know is the ratio of each Blue and Red dots like picture below.

[image]

Is there any tools to do this in sklearn or tensorflow? or should I make my own k-nn model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sklearn does that ! Check [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) out. [Predict_proba](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba) is the function you want.

You will have your probabilities for each class, just multiply it by K to have the actual number you want :

```
X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

K = 3

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=K)
neigh.fit(X, y)

print(neigh.predict([[1.1]]))

predicted = neigh.predict_proba([[0.9]]) # -> [[0.66666667 0.33333333]]

whatYouWant = K*predicted

print(whatYouWant) #-> [[2,1]]
print("Number of 0 : ",whatYouWant[0][0]) # -> Number of 0 :  2.0
print("Number of 1 : ",whatYouWant[0][1]) # -> Number of 1 :  1.0
print("Total : ",sum(whatYouWant[0])) # -> Total :  3.0 which is K
```